# format number in pd.to_json()

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do that:

```
y = 0.2            => y = 0.200
x = 0.24524452     => x = 0.245
```

I made the following request, to keep 3 numbers after the commas

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{: .3f}'. format
```

but when I use :

```
pd.to_json('path')
```

I find in the file contains :

```
y = 0.2
x = 0.245
```

why the to_json function removes zero?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to add a `double_precision` argument when saving:

```
df    
     a         b      c
0  0.2  0.245673  1.235

df.to_json(double_precision=3)
'{"a":{"0":0.2},"b":{"0":0.246},"c":{"0":1.235}}'
```

Note that 0.2 cannot be saved as 0.200 as long as you want the value to remain numeric.

You can, however, convert to string. Example,

```
df.applymap('{:.3f}'.format).to_json()
'{"a":{"0":"0.200"},"b":{"0":"0.246"},"c":{"0":"1.235"}}'
```

Comment: Thank you , so I can not get 0.200 without the quotation marks ?

Comment: @DataScientist No, sorry.